# Webkit and C# Repair script

Tags: javascript, c#, webkit

Ok, I make a simple app in C# that worked ok, alot of things didn't work right because it required me to click javascript links. So started another project and this time I used webkit, everything function perfect after the switch except one item. I need some assistance repairing this to work with webkit because it is the main function of my app. I have never used webkit before I don't know where to start.

```
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection elems = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
        {
            String value = elem.GetAttribute("value");
            if (elem.InnerText == "Recruit")
            {
                elem.InvokeMember("click");
            }

        }
    }
```

Before the switch this worked, Now I have a error:

```
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebKit.DOM.NodeList' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection'    C:\Users\Mass\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  48  43  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I need to keep it as is with GetElementsByTagName I cannot switch to GetElementbyId.

Edit: to any who may find this helpful, The last set of errors I had had to do with innertext. after reading webkit documents I fount that it does not use inner text but TextContent.

```
 //Looks for the value of the tag
            String value = ele.GetAttribute("value");
            //If innertext = value perform click
            if (ele.TextContent == "Recruit")
            {
                //invoke a click here
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried this `HtmlElementCollection elems = (System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection)web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");`

Comment: Yes, Its the same error.

Comment: Is it an error or an exception after implementing the above suggested code

Comment: `Error 3 Cannot convert type 'WebKit.DOM.NodeList' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection' C:\Users\Mass\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 48 43 WindowsFormsApplication1
`

Comment: so do you have any problem in writing this `WebKit.DOM.NodeList elems = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a‌​");`

Comment: Just that part alone, no errors. When I add the rest to get the attribute to perform the click yes.

Comment: If you write the above line to get all the Document elements then you should change your foreach loop as `foreach(WebKit.DOM.Element ele in elems)`

Comment: Thank you I still have a couple errors but I think I can figure them out

Comment: Okay then, i am posting it as answer if it is helpful please mark it as answer so that others can be benifited

Comment: It wont let me, I dont have enough rep to vote it up

Comment: But you can mark it as answer

Comment: `ele.InvokeMember("click");` Sorry one last question on this topic.

Comment: It says that InvokeMember is not apart of it. Is there another way to perform the click. Besides `.GetScriptManager.EvaluateScript("document.getElementById('myButton').click();");`

Comment: The code you posted is not invoking the click

Comment: I'm beginning to hate webkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows and do necessary changes

```
WebKit.DOM.NodeList elems = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a‌​");
foreach(WebKit.DOM.Element ele in elems)
{
  //Statements 
}
```